# Multithreading with MVP & violation in Android

Tags: java, android, mvp

I want to convert my project according to MVP structure, & I had done it but it violate the MVP design, as it holds the activity instance in the presenter layer.

So, I just wanted to know how can I convert this project into pure MVP. Here Validation class is recursive and validate many fields & for here it is just for signup, and I had put the Validate method into separate thread.

This is my MVP interface

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class IMVP_Login {

/**
 * View mandatory methods. Available to Presenter
 *      Presenter -> View
 */
public interface RequiredViewOps {
    void showToast(String msg);
}

/**
 * Operations offered from Presenter to View
 *      View -> Presenter
 */
public interface PresenterOps{
    void submit(Activity activity);
}
}
```

This is my presenter with thread and containing the activity instance, which is against the design pattern of MVP, the code is as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import cp.utility.CustomException;
import cp.utility.Validation;

public class PresenterLogin implements Runnable,IMVP_Login.PresenterOps
{
private WeakReference<IMVP_Login.RequiredViewOps> mView;

// this is against the architectural law of MVP
private WeakReference<Activity> activity;

public PresenterLogin(IMVP_Login.RequiredViewOps mView) {
    this.mView = new WeakReference<>(mView);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        Validation.validate(activity.get());
    }catch (CustomException e)
    {
        mView.get().showToast(e.getMessage());
    }
}

//how should i do this with MVP PATTERN,as it is holding the activity instance
@Override
public void submit(Activity activity) {
    this.activity=new WeakReference<>(activity);
    Thread validationThread = new Thread(this,"Validation");
    validationThread.start();
}
}
```

This is my activity,

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,IMVP_Login.RequiredViewOps
{
private TextInputEditText edPhone,edCountrycode,edPassword;
private IMVP_Login.PresenterOps presenterLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

    initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    presenterLogin= new PresenterLogin(this);
    Button btSignIn=GeneralFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(this,R.id.btnSignIn);
    btSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

    edCountrycode = GeneralFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(this, R.id.etCode);
    edPhone = GeneralFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(this, R.id.etPhone);
    edPassword = GeneralFunction.findViewByIdAndCast(this, R.id.etPassword);
    edPassword.setTypeface(Typekit.getInstance().get(getString(R.string.str_regular)));
    edPassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnSignIn:
            presenterLogin.submit(this);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void showToast(String msg) {
    //show toast
}
}
```

This is the validation class depending on tag of editext,

```
public class Validation {

public static boolean validateFields(final ViewGroup parentView) throws CustomException
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++)
    {

        if (parentView.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
            if ((parentView.getChildAt(i)).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                validateFields((ViewGroup) parentView.getChildAt(i));
        }
        else if((parentView.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView) && ((parentView.getChildAt(i)).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE))
        {
            TextView editText = (TextView) parentView.getChildAt(i);
            if(null!=editText.getTag())
            {
                String type = editText.getTag().toString().toLowerCase();
                String text=GeneralFunction.getTextFromView(editText);
                //validation depending on tag
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean validate(Activity activity) {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        return validateFields(viewGroup);
}
```

}

Comment: Please check this example ... https://github.com/konmik/konmik.github.io/wiki/Introduction-to-Model-View-Presenter-on-Android

Comment: @thestalker, but that examples also violates the mvp, as according to mvp the presenter shouldn't have the knowledge of view, but here and in shared link same things happen.

Comment: Don't have a reference to the activity.  https://github.com/konmik/testable-activity-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/info/android15/testableactivity/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that there are many different ways of doing MVP, each of them valid in their own right.  The important things to keep in mind are:

- The View should not know about the model, it doesn't care at all where its data is coming from.
- The Presenter should not know about Android. You should be able to run your Presenter class entirely on the JVM.
- Your Activity/Fragment/ViewGroup should implement the View interface which is how the Presenter communicates with them.

Why do we do this?

1. **Separation of concerns**.
   You can change the network library you use in your Model and the View/Presenter should just work still.  You could switch your View from a horizontal ViewPager to a vertical RecyclerView and the Presenter/Model equally wouldn't care.
2. **Testing**.
   We can mock our Presenter and unit test the View or Model.  Mock the View & Model and unit test the Presenter.

As long as the implementation of MVP that you are using allows the above then in my mind it is valid.

Onto your specific problem.  I would set it up something like this:

View:

```
public interface LoginView {

    Map<String,String> getLoginFields();
}
```

Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginView {

    private EditText emailView;
    private EditText phoneView;
    private EditText passwordView;
    private Button loginView;

    private LoginPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        presenter = new LoginPresenter();
        presenter.bindView(this);

        emailView = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        phoneView = findViewById(R.id.login_phone);
        passwordView = findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        loginView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presenter.login();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        presenter.unbindView();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getLoginFields() {

        Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();

        fields.put(emailView.getTag().toString(), emailView.getText().toString());
        fields.put(phoneView.getTag().toString(), phoneView.getText().toString());
        fields.put(passwordView.getTag().toString(), passwordView.getText().toString());

        return fields;
    }
}
```

You may wish to do something fancy with the getLoginFields method and loop through your container.  Even if you had 100 fields though it shouldn't require offloading onto another thread. I'd be a very upset user if I had to fill out 100 fields...

Presenter:

```
public class LoginPresenter {

    private LoginView view;
    private LoginValidator validator;

    public void bindView(LoginView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void unbindView() {
        view = null;
    }

    public void login() {

        validator = new LoginValidator();
        Map<String, String> fields = view.getLoginFields();
        boolean isValid = validator.validate(fields);
    }
}
```

Validator:

```
public class LoginValidator {

    public boolean validate(Map<String, String> fields) {

        //validation depending on tag
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Threading**

If the need does arise to process something on another thread in the Activity then you have several approaches you could take:

1. Pass a listener to the `getLoginFields()` method which gets called when the work is done.
2. Expose another method in the Presenter, something like `onLoginFieldsProcessed` which would get called once the work is done.
3. Have `getLoginFields()` return `Observable` (RxJava) or `Future`.

I would personally probably use RxJava, especially if I was already using it in the app.

Comment: you are right, but what should i do, if such a requirement come up.

Comment: I've added a short summary of what could be done if you had to use concurrency.

Comment: Much appreciated answer,  it will be great if you can further elaborate the threading part with some short example

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why there is separate presenter class added in this MVP framework ( especially in android ) is to remove the OutOfMemory or if by chance the activity fails the presenter calls is not affected i.e why there is MVP approach followed instead of MV framework.

Consider the below example that is from below link :-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Chuck Norris";

    private ArrayAdapter<ServerAPI.Item> adapter;
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item));
        requestItems(DEFAULT_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unsubscribe();
    }

    public void requestItems(String name) {
        unsubscribe();
        subscription = App.getServerAPI()
            .getItems(name.split("\\s+")[0], name.split("\\s+")[1])
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<ServerAPI.Response>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ServerAPI.Response response) {
                    onItemsNext(response.items);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable error) {
                    onItemsError(error);
                }
            });
    }

    public void onItemsNext(ServerAPI.Item[] items) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(items);
    }

    public void onItemsError(Throwable throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void unsubscribe() {
        if (subscription != null) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
            subscription = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example the activity failure causes the presenter layer to stop working .Similarly ,if there is any object associated with this  activity class ( View ) will be affected .

Referencing by `static` will make the activity die out while there is a crash but the presenter class will not be affected.( Please refer to below code for MVP ).

```
public class MainPresenter {

    public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "Chuck Norris";

    private ServerAPI.Item[] items;
    private Throwable error;

    private MainActivity view;

    public MainPresenter() {
        App.getServerAPI()
            .getItems(DEFAULT_NAME.split("\\s+")[0], DEFAULT_NAME.split("\\s+")[1])
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<ServerAPI.Response>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ServerAPI.Response response) {
                    items = response.items;
                    publish();
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    error = throwable;
                    publish();
                }
            });
    }

    public void onTakeView(MainActivity view) {
        this.view = view;
        publish();
    }

    private void publish() {
        if (view != null) {
            if (items != null)
                view.onItemsNext(items);
            else if (error != null)
                view.onItemsError(error);
        }
    }
}  


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayAdapter<ServerAPI.Item> adapter;

    private static MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item));

        if (presenter == null)
            presenter = new MainPresenter();
        presenter.onTakeView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        presenter.onTakeView(null);
        if (!isChangingConfigurations())
            presenter = null;
    }

    public void onItemsNext(ServerAPI.Item[] items) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(items);
    }

    public void onItemsError(Throwable throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

MainActivity creates MainPresenter and keeps it outside of reach of onCreate/onDestroy cycle. MainActivity uses a static variable to reference MainPresenter, so every time a process restarts due to out-of-memory event, MainActivity should check if the presenter is still here and create it if needed.( As stated in the doc ).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but the MainPresenter holds the reference of MainActivity, and it violates the MVP architecture, as according to MVP, presenter should have no knowledge of View or activity., so, that's an incorrect answer

Comment: @thestaler, any way thanks but i want an answer which can satisfy me.